# Show that a geometric series is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sin(k)$ is bounded.

I really don't know how to go about, and don't see any criteria that are suited to this problem.

Comment: are you really sure?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - It is bounded - for example by $2$ in absolute terms

Comment: @Henry I suspect his error was the same as mine (I deleted my comment when I realised it) - bounded does not necessarily imply convergent.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: To check if the sum is bounded, calculate its partial sums using Eulers identity $2i\sin(k)=e^{ik}-e^{-ik}$ and the geometric series.

Answer (score 3):

The partial sums are

$S_n=sin(1)+sin(2)+...+sin(n)$

$C_n=cos(1)+cos(2)+...+cos(n)$

$C_n+iS_n=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik}$

$=e^i\frac{1-e^{in}}{1-e^i}$

$=e^{\frac{(n+1)i}{2}} $

$\frac{sin(\frac{n}{2})}{sin(\frac{1}{2})}$

take imaginary part and notice that

$|S_n|\leq\frac{1}{sin(0.5)}$.

Comment: How do you know that $\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ik} = e^i\frac{1-e^{in}}{1-e^i}$ ?

Comment: @aribaldi it is geometric series

Comment: Shouldn't it be  = $\dfrac{1}{1-e^i}$?

Comment: @aribaldi no. take modulus

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "take the modulus". If you mean take the modulus of $e^{ik}$ isn't it 1?

Comment: @aribaldi what is the sum $a+a^2+a^3+....a^n$.

Comment: True, It's $\dfrac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$

Comment: @aribaldi no it's $a\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46806/discussion-between-aribaldi-and-abdallah-hammam).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you would like to consider the partial sum
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sin(k).$$

Hint. Show by induction that
$$S_n= \frac{\cos\frac{1}{2}-\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\sin\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Since $|\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)|\not=1$ for any integer $n$, this identity implies that 
$$ −0.127671 \approx\frac{\cos\frac{1}{2}-1}{2\sin\frac{1}{2}}<S_n< \frac{\cos\frac{1}{2}+1}{2\sin\frac{1}{2}}\approx 1.958159.$$
See Henry's chart.

Comment: So bounds of about $-0.127671$ and $1.958159$ - see my chart which illustrates this

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but the chart of partial sums would not fit in a comment box:

[image]

By comparison, Robert Z's answer gives bounds of about $-0.127671$ and $1.958159$